# upgrade issue from 12.04

Tags: software-center

Im trying to do a system upgrade from 12.04 and I walked through the steps in update manager as it stats online but it doesn't tell me that a new update is available for ubuntu.  It just tells me my system is up to date.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you start the update-manager go to the preferences and change on the third tab to check for every new version (not only long term support).